# How do use a list to sum only the rows containing certain data?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that contains the following type of data

> ```
> 2182016           |          CASH RECEIPT        |       3055 
> 2182016           |          POSTAGE RA          |       2116 
> 2182016           |          CASH RECEIPT        |       2509
> ```

This list with this type of data will go for hundreds of rows, with the dates, transaction descriptions, and other fields not shown duplicating many times depending on deliveries.  I need to take every occurrence of a description and sum the retail fees then copy the line to a new worksheet maintaining the other columns as a single record For example if the three lines above were the entire worksheet I would need the output onto a new worksheet as follows:

> ```
> 2182016           |          CASH RECEIPT        |       5564 
> 2182016           |          POSTAGE RA          |       2116
> ```

Also, sometimes the number in the field I need to sum is preceded by a 1 in another column, this means the data needs to be subtracted not added.

> ```
> 2182016           |          CASH RECEIPT        |    |   3055    
> 2182016           |          POSTAGE RA          |    |   2116
> 2182016           |          CASH RECEIPT        |  1 |   2509
> ```

Would need to be output like this

> ```
> 2182016           |          CASH RECEIPT        |    |    549 
> 2182016           |          POSTAGE RA          |    |   2116
> ```

I have the full list of description I will need to sum totals for in a hidden sheet

> Store Supply,Store Equipment,Groc Purchases,Produce Purch,Meat Purch,Frozen Purch,Dairy Purch,Deli Purch,HBA Purch,Tobacco Purch,Fuel,EPS Fees,Cpn Face,Cpn Inc,Training,Valassis,Rebate 1,Rebate 2,Rebate 3,Rebate 4,Rebate 5,Rebate 6,WHSE SALES,Office Supply,Office Equip,Office Training,Office Rental,Note Install,Note Credit,Note Interest,VPN

Comment: How about a pivot table? In a pivot table you could also use a calculated field for the (subtract if there is a preceding 1).

Comment: Unfortunately a pivot table won't work, this will be primarily used to process data from a text file and then produce an export.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,2182016,B:B,"CASH RECEIPT",C:C,"<>" & 1)-SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,2182016,B:B,"CASH RECEIPT",C:C,1)
```

This is based on your second example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a module-level User-defined Type to dump your running totals into, and write a loop of code that scrolls down the "TEXT" columns, and matches the string to the appropriate Case.

```
 Type DescriptionTotals
        Dim storeSupply As Double
        Dim producePurch As Double
        Dim anotherThing As Double
        '... you get the picture here
    End Type


sub getTotals()

dim matchString As String
'do something here to select a cell, and assign to "matchString"
cells(i,j).value = matchString

Select Case matchString
    Case Is "CASH RECIEPT"
        DescriptionTotals.cashReceipt = DescriptionTotals.cashReceipt + 'value in adjacent cell
    Case is "NEXT COMPARISON STRING"
        'add to the total in your type here.
    Case Else
        'handle string match errors here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe to be the easiest solution. Add a calculated column to your existing table. This column should be calculated as

```
=IF(columnWithPrefix=1,-1,1)*columnWithTransactionCount)
```

Then you can select the entire table and click in the menu `Insert` and then `Pivot Table`. Afterwards, it is merely a matter of you formatting the table to your personal preference. Here is a simple solution based on your sample data.
[image]

Some comments:

- I have a European Version of Excel and therefore you see `;` in the
  formula where you have potentially `,` instead.
- The performance should be (even with a couple thousand rows) very
  good.
- You can double-click on any value to drill-down.
- If you format the date in a recognizable date format then Excel even
  allows you (automatically) to summarize by year, quarter, month, or day.